# Scroll To Top Button not working in Child templates

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrolltop, vapor, leaf

I have added the [Scroll Back To Top Button](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_to_top.asp) in my Base template and it's working perfectly. But when I go to any other pages, the button won't work. Why?!

Here is my Base template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>

  <body>
    <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>
    .
    .
    <div class="container">
      #import("content") 
    </div>
    .
    .
  </body>
</html>
```

And I'm using the JavaScript from the above link:

```
window.onscroll = function() { scrollFunction() };

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    $('#myBtn').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('#myBtn').fadeOut();
  }
}

function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
}
```

The button is only working on the homepage, but not on any other pages even though I see (from View Page Source) `<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>` is in the body. Can anyone please help??

Comment: It seems likely your Javascript is only rendering on the base page, not on all. Can you open a debug console (web inspector, Javascript console, etc) and see if any warnings or errors are reported?

Comment: ooops! your are absolutely correct...there was a "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined" error that i didn't notice, and after fixing it, the button is working ^_^ :D thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above is actually correct and the button is working perfectly on every page now. After **tobygriffin** pointed out, I noticed that there was a `Cannot read property 'style' of undefined` error that I didn't before. The button is working on all pages after fixing that error.

Even though it was a silly mistake on my part, I am keeping this Q&A (not deleting it) hoping someone might find it useful :)

Comment: It won't give you any rep, but you should mark your answer as accepted. That way people browsing the questions will know that your question has been resolved.

Comment: I will, ASA it lets me :) Thank you